# plot several runs of BehaviorSpace in one plot

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I want one plot to display the results of 100 model runs. Do I have to use Excel or is there a way within Netlogo?
I found the proposal to use create-temporary-plot-pen, but i did not manage to find out how this will do the job.

Comment: You can write the desired data from each run to a file (e.g., in CSV format) and write a separate NetLogo program to read the data and plot it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `clear-all`, as it will clear all of the plots. Start each run by using a more limited set of clearing commands (e.g., `clear-turtles`, `clear-patches`, `reset-ticks`, and so forth). Then each run can add data to an existing plot.

If you do this you may want to offer your user multiple setup buttons, one that clears everything, and one that only sets up the current run.

Comment: Ok, but now the new plot does not start at x=0 but where the old plot stopped. I want all plots to be in the range 0-30.  I tried out several options i could think of (eg. set-plot-x-range) but the problem ist still there... Many thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Do you use the `plot` or the `plotxy` command for the plot pen updates? Maybe try `plotxy ticks your-variable` instead of `plot your-variable`?